# Running an infinite loop because of next_permute

Tags: c++

I am trying to solve a problem where I input two vectors of different lengths and add their scalar product. Its the minimun scalar product problem from https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/32016/dashboard#s=p0  . I'm apparently hopelessly running an infinite loop.Probably because of the permutation.But I don't understand why .

```
#include "stdafx.h";
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

//output stuff
int cases[100];
int casesol[100];
int ncase;
void output()
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= ncase; i++)
    {
        printf("Case #%d: %d\n", i, casesol[i]);
    }
}

//output stuff end
int product;
int v1[100];
int v2[100];
int minimum;
int main()
{

    // read in number of cases
    freopen("file.in", "r", stdin);
    freopen("file.out", "w", stdout);
    scanf("%d", &ncase);

    // read in misc problem constants
    for (int i = 1; i <= ncase; ++i) {
        int vector_size;
        scanf("%d", &vector_size);

        // read in data

        //v1= new int [vector_size];
        //v2=new int [vector_size];

        for (int j = 0; j < vector_size; ++j){
            scanf("%d", &v1[j]);
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < vector_size; ++j){
            scanf("%d", &v2[j]);
        }

        // problem solving logic here
        do{
            for (int j = 0; j < vector_size; ++j){
                product += v1[j] * v2[j];
            }
            if (product<minimum)
                minimum = product;
        } while (next_permutation(v2 + 0, v2 + (vector_size - 1)));
        casesol[i] = minimum;
    }
    output();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Make the number of permutations reasonably small and step through with a debugger.

Comment: `next_permutation` is O(N!) complexity.  100! is 9.332622e+157 possibilities.

Comment: but i'm  taking input as vector_size and have last parameter of next_permuatation set to v2[vector_size-1], which should get that problem out of the way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment @NathanOliver made was correct.  I think the problem here is in your design.  There is a much easier solution to the problem you are looking at; the minimum scalar vector is just the max of one vector multiplied times the min of the other vector.  Consider the code below:

```
const int size = 3;

std::vector<int> v1 {1, 3, -5};
std::vector<int> v2 {-2, 4, 1};

std::sort(v1.begin(), v1.end());
std::sort(v2.begin(), v2.end());

int product = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    product += v1[i] * v2[size-1-i];
}
```

This is the first example from the page you linked (hard coded instead of reading from a file).  The result I get is correct, `-25`.

Comment: thats smart ! i complicated too much. this is stupid but.. is there any trick to finding simple solutions like this one for any problem ?

Comment: @user4684729 no I don't think so.  I think part of the code jam problem was coming up with a good mathematical solution, as well as a good software one.